# Javascript Display block when a button is clicked doesn't work on mobile

Tags: javascript, dom, click, addeventlistener

I have this function that checks whether something inside a certain div is clicked. A part of the function checks if the targeted button has a certain class. This works perfectly, but when I go to mobile it doesn't work like I want it to.

```
btn.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        if (!tgt.className.indexOf('nextbtn')) {
            navi.NextBtn();
            let dots = document.getElementsByClassName('owl-dots')[0];
            dots.style.display = 'block';
        }
})
```

I did a ! in the if statement because somehow it is reversed (I don't know why). If I remove it it won't do anything. On my computer it works perfectly, but when I go to mobile it doesn't change the style to block, but it does run the NextBtn function. Does anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: the targeted button should be event.target .. how did you populate the tgt var? and what does navi.NextBtn()? everything else is supposed to be ok. By the way indexOf() returns the index where the found string starts in the subject string or -1 if nothing was found. If you negate that value it will always be false both when the string is found or not. So the if statement won't ever be executed at all. So I doubt it ever worked both on mobile and desktop

Comment: Actually the negated version you used will return true only when indexOf() returns 0 ... it means only when the string you are looking for "nextBtn" happens at the beginning of the string tgt.className

Comment: @DiegoDeVita The tgt variable does mean event.target and the only thing thats inside nav.NextBtn is a count variable that counts 1 everytime you click it. That works on mobile and pc, but the display does not

Comment: @DiegoDeVita But what's wrong with that?

Comment: ok tgt means target but the javascript interpreter doesn't know it. It's your choice and you should tell him somehow like: `tgt = event.target`. But yet your logic is flawed. Instead of using `if(!tgt.className.indexOf('nextbtn'))` you should do `if ( event.target.className.includes('nextbtn') )` and yet it would be a little dirty because there's a chance that nextbtn was part of another longer classname. Anyway in that case it will enter the if condition if the current event target contains the class nextbtn among its own

Comment: but in general as a rule I suggest you to split your problems in smaller problems. So if you wanted to understand if there are differences between how an element gets shown or hidden on a desktop browser compared to a mobile browser, the strategy could be to first address that detail crafting a single button that will run a given action like hiding an element with no conditions on top. If that works you find out that your problem lies in any surrounding stuff like a precondition and you address the next issue following the same criteria. One by one

Comment: @DiegoDeVita Thanks man I will. For now I have a fix but thanks!